# Folder delete in full permission

Tags: c#

I want to delete the C:\Windows\Web folder but not deleted.

[image: Error]

how to Folder delete in full permission?

I using the code :

```
        string folderepath = @"C:\Windows\Web\4K";

        if (Directory.Exists(folderepath))
        {
            Directory.Delete(folderepath, true);
        }
```

Comment: if its win app run your app on run as administrator mode maybe it work?

Comment: You don't have permissions to delete that folder. Via code or manually..
If your code should delete that folder, you need to either manually change permissions for that folder (BAD) or run your application elevated ("Run as administrator")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have enough privileges to do this, because you're messing with the OS installation folder. To solve the problem you either need to manually change permissions, or to run your application in "Run as admin" mode.

Personally, I'd prefer to write my application so as the Windows folder remains untouched. Fewer problems down the road.

Comment: Not as far as I know.